# Вылет приложения при добавлении элемента в ListView(android)

Tags: java, android

приложение вылетает при добавлении элемента в ListView, не могу понять в чем причина, буду благодарен за помощь.

```
package com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by jone1 on 28.05.2018.
 */

public class Menu6 extends Fragment {
    private ImageView ImageViewForLoad;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private ListView lvMain;
    ArrayList<String> selectedPhones = new ArrayList();
    String[] list_for_image = {"dsds"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //returning our layout file
        //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments

// inflate mainXML

// find container

        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        //int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        //int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_6, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,250,222,165));
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.content);

        layout.addView(new Menu6.DrawView(view.getContext()));

// находим список
        lvMain = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_for_image);

        new ParseTask().execute();
        //R.integer.pass
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        getActivity().setTitle("Галлерея");
    }

    private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String resultJson = "";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://91.226.82.163:8000/api/v1/gallery/checklog/");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token " + globalvariable.ClientToken);
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return resultJson;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
            super.onPostExecute(strJson);
            // выводим целиком полученную json-строку
            Log.d("ggg:", strJson);
            String text_in_strJson = "";
            boolean start_read = false;
            boolean photo_read = false;
            boolean created_dt_read = false;
            String[] jpg_array = new String[10000];
            list_for_image = new String[10000];
            int jpg_count = 0;
            int dt_count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < strJson.length(); ++i){
                if (strJson.charAt(i) == '"'){
                    if (photo_read == true && start_read == true) {
                        photo_read = false;
                        ++jpg_count;
                    }
                    if (created_dt_read == true && start_read == true) {
                        created_dt_read = false;
                        ++dt_count;
                    }
                    start_read = !start_read;
                    if (text_in_strJson.equals("photo")){
                        photo_read = true;
                        jpg_array[jpg_count] = "";
                    }
                    if (text_in_strJson.equals("created_dt")) {
                        created_dt_read = true;
                        list_for_image[jpg_count] = "";
                    }
                        text_in_strJson = "";
                }
                else{
                    if (start_read == true){
                        text_in_strJson += strJson.charAt(i);
                        if (photo_read == true){
                            jpg_array[jpg_count] += strJson.charAt(i);
                        }
                        if (created_dt_read == true){
                            list_for_image[dt_count] += strJson.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < jpg_count; ++i){
                add(getView(), list_for_image[i]);
            }



            JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;
            String secondName = "";
            //Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(jpg_array[1]).into(ImageViewForLoad);
        }

        public void add(View view, String str){
            if(!str.isEmpty()){
                adapter.add(str);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    class DrawView extends View {

        Paint p;
        Rect rect;
        Paint paint;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Rect rectSrc;
        Rect rectDst;
        Matrix matrix;

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            rect = new Rect();
            paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        }
    }
}
```

Код ошибки:

> 06-22 16:10:00.875 5624-5624/com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer, PID: 5624
>                                                                                      java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>                                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
>                                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
>                                                                                          at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(ArrayAdapter.java:197)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu6$ParseTask.add(Menu6.java:186)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu6$ParseTask.onPostExecute(Menu6.java:174)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer.Menu6$ParseTask.onPostExecute(Menu6.java:91)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>                                                                                          at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

Comment: а что у вас в 186 строке? `.Menu6$ParseTask.add(Menu6.java:186)`

Comment: @Jarvis_J, adapter.add(str); он на нее как раз ругается

Answer (score 2):

Если адаптеру в конструктор передан массив или неизменяемый список - операции добавления и удаления не поддерживаются.
Нужно создать нормальный список и передать в конструктор адаптера его.
Или вообще ничего не передавать, а добавлять методами `add` адаптера:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
adapter.add(list_for_image);
```